# Computed property names cannot be received if set by a numeric variable

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Sorry for ambiguous title, I just can't think up anything clearer :)

The problem is in the object spread and computed property syntax. Consider following example:

```
const state = { foo: 'bar' };
const id = 3;

const newState = {
  [id]: 'three', // A
  ...state
}

const {
  [id]: omit, // B
  ...nextState
} = newState;
```

While using [object rest spread syntax](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-object-rest-spread/) to immutably remove a property from object (it is useful in Redux reducers), I cannot use same variable as I used to set this property in line A.

Here, I expect `nextState` to be `{ foo: 'bar' }`, but I get it `{ '3': 'three', foo: 'bar' }`.

However, if I manually convert to string property  in line B, I will have expected results.

```
const {
  [id.toString()]: omit,
  ...nextState
} = newState;
```

Now `nextState` is `{ '3': 'three', foo: 'bar' }`.

What is going on here? Is it expected behaviour in ES7 or Babel bug?

Here is an example: http://www.es6fiddle.net/im23ggzk/

Comment: Works just fine on babel http://www.es6fiddle.net/im22ornn/, i think you might be checking `newState` instead of `nextState`.

Comment: @MinusFour: No, that is because destructively assign form `state`, not `newState`. It is my fault, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in the experimental babel plugin. You can see the transpiled code:

```
function _objectWithoutProperties(obj, keys) {
    var target = {};
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (keys.indexOf(i) >= 0) continue;
        if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, i)) continue;
        target[i] = obj[i];
    }
    return target;
}

var nextState = _objectWithoutProperties(newState, [id]);
```

The `indexOf` test uses the [Strict Equality Comparison](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-equality-comparison) which distinguishes between types, and does therefore not find your number. A fix would be `_objectWithoutProperties(newState, [id].map(_ToPropertyKey))`.